# Show both of the same Daylight Savings Time hour with SciChart.WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, scichart

How does SciChart support Daylight savings time? I have a set of timeseries data that is logged in UTC but displayed in local time. This means that there will be two sets of 1 hour depending on the local time zone. I can show the data in an unsorted manner, but then the data is just drawn twice in the same period of the same hour. How do I get scichart to show 1-1:59 twice during Daylight Savings time.

Comment: The only solution we found was not to run any tests the night the clocks are set backwards.  You could sort by UTC and then add an offset to each value to get local time which would eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: @jdweng Missing data or not running is not really an option in a production environment. Application is running 24/7 and is auditable data by government bodies.

Comment: Then use UTC which is what most people would do.

Comment: A long, long time ago (the 80s), we ended up producing a set of report formats that were good only on one day a year (we just showed a blank hour on the reports during the spring time change).  In the fall, the reports showed something like 1:00am ... 1:59am ... +1:00am ... +1:59am ... 2:00 am, and then normally. An eight hour shift report ended up covering 9 hours of data